# Handling Failed eloquent methods

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm calling a product's information field, as you can see below:

```
$product->attributes->first()->attributeValues->where('locale',$iso);
```

Basically in the `$product` variable already have information regarding the product.

I use `$product->attributes->first()` to get his attributes, and after getting them I go get his values with `->attributeValues->where('locale',$iso)` with the specific language.

The data it outputs is good, but only if attributes exist, because in case there isn't any it doesn't and because of the `attributeValues` method the page fails.

How can I handle in this situation?

Comment: Where are you calling this? In Model or Controller?

Answer (score 0):

You may check it with a simple `empty()` or even `count()` if you prefer.

```php
$attributes = $product->attributes->first()->attributeValues->where('locale',$iso);

if (count($attributes) == 0) {
    // There is no attribute, do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split up your line

```
$attributes = $product->attributes->first(); // placeholder

if(isset($attributes) { // check if we have one
  $attributes->attributeValues->where('locale',$iso); // if so.. do the dance
} else {// go home }
```